# How to set an alert in Selenium RC using C# in .cs file?

Tags: selenium

Purpose:

To convert the following code from Selenium IDE to RC in C#.

```
<tr>
  <td>storeEval</td>
  <td>alert("Please Enter the Verification code");</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

To set pause for enter Captcha value. in a loop. its working fine in IDE.

Tried with the converted code it shows as the following but VS08 shows Synax error.

```
String  = selenium.GetEval("alert(\"Please Enter the Verification code\");");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result to a *variable*. `String` is a class name/type, not a variable name:

```
string result  = selenium.GetEval("alert(\"Please Enter the Verification code\");");
```

Then you can assert on the result.